# Fade image to transparent like a gradient

Tags: css, gradient

I would like to have an image (a background image) to fade to transparent so that content behind it can actually be seen (barely, thanks to transparency).

I can achieve it obviously with a PNG image, but I need to ask to my graphic designer to change the image every time I want to change the start => stop transparency points (maybe I want more color or maybe I want less color and more transparency).

Are there any chance I can achieve the same effect with CSS3? I tried applying a gradient to transparent on a jpg (and a png) but I can't see through it unless the PNG has already transparency (and basically the gradient) already done (which makes the css gradient useless).

Any suggestion? I'm digging hard through the web but seems like I'm not using the right keyword or maybe it's not possible.

**Update 1:**

Code says more than a lot of words, I would like to do something like this (but the syntax is obviously wrong):

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(url('splash_bottom3.png'), 0.0), rgba(url('splash_bottom3.png'), 1.0));
```

Comment: You need to search for "masking". Dificult to get it working cross-browser, though.

Comment: Ohhh, your suggestion is really good, I wasn't looking for the right keyword as it appear. Ok I'm checking a bit around the web, I'm ok with supporting only IE10+/chrome last version/firefox last version. If I have problem with those, obviously I can't use it.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If you want this:

[image]

You can do this:

```html
<html>
  <style type='text/css'>
    div, img { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; width:250px; height:250px; }
    img {
      -webkit-mask-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0,0,0,1)), to(rgba(0,0,0,0)));
      mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1), rgba(0,0,0,0));
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi sit amet porttitor massa. Morbi eget tortor congue, aliquet odio a, viverra metus. Ut cursus enim eu felis sollicitudin, vitae eleifend urna lobortis. Mauris elementum erat non facilisis cursus. Fusce sit amet lacus dictum, porta libero sed, euismod tellus. Aenean erat augue, sodales sed gravida ac, imperdiet ac augue. Ut condimentum dictum mauris. Donec tincidunt enim a massa molestie, vel volutpat massa dictum. Donec semper odio vitae adipiscing lacinia.</div>
    <img src='https://i.imgur.com/sLa5gg2.jpg' />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea but in this way, the image won't be transparent, am I wrong? So if I have some text BEHIND the #under div, I can't see it through image.

I was testing something similar to this previously.

Comment: Correct, the image won't be transparent.  If you have text behind #under it will be covered (assuming natural stacking order).  You can get around that with z-index.  I'm posting an update in my answer.

Comment: The problem is that I need text to fade behind the image, that's my main purpose.

Comment: Now your answer is much better, yes I'm working on the same, webkit-mask-image. It looks like on firefox it works with mask-image (without -webkit) but you **have to use an svg image**, I'm trying to build one

Comment: Could you not layer a bit of opacity over the image if you want to read the text?

Comment: Had to use `-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 75%);` for a left to right gradient with a stop point at 75%. The syntax above didn't make any sense ("left top to left bottom"?). https://webkit.org/blog/1424/css3-gradients/

Comment: Firefox does support `mask-image`

Answer (score 25):

If you just want to fade to the background color (white, in this case) see the working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/yw9v7zm5/

.css for the image container div uses:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(80%,rgba(255,255,255,1)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 80%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 );
```

Comment: This solution is working on all the IE/FF/Chrome/Safari I could test using BrowserStack!

Comment: Asker specified that he wants content to be visible behind the fade.

Comment: You can put the code from this into another container so that the background is transparent behind it, and this fades out (into the transparent background), so things are visible behind it

Comment: fiddle no longer works due to the missing image background.

Answer (score 19):

2021 update:
'mask-image' is partially supported. The mask image (In this case a linear-gradient) is set on the parent element (.image_preview_container). The children (.image_preview) start fading into transparency at 50% in this example. Then are completely transparent at 100%. (Can also use other lengths like 'px')

It's working in firefox. And possibly in others. This worked for me so far. Please comment if doesn't work for your browser.

CSS:

```
.image_preview_container {
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0) 50%, transparent 100%);
}
.image_preview {
  background-image: url("IMAGE LOCATION");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="image_preview_container">
    <div class="image_preview"></div>
</div>
```

In the context of the original question:

CSS:

```
.parent{
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0) 50%, transparent 100%);
}
.child{
  background-image: url("splash_bottom3.png");
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/css-masks currently no support for IE or Opera Mini

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I'm not sure about multiple browser support but worked for chrome. Will have to do some research for Safari most likely. Apple has to make everything difficult

Comment: @LukeBrown, I doubt a browser that was released almost a decade ago will support many of these advanced features without a significant js shiv in place, if it's even possible at all.

Comment: this is much nicer than the current answer and doesn't force us to use webkit