# Fade two images together in CSS

Tags: css, image, transparency

Say I have these two images:

[image]
[image]

How do I combine them [like this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/38952/how-to-fade-two-images-together-in-sketch), where one fades gradually into the other, using just CSS?

[image]

I need to do this using CSS because the images are user-supplied.

I've tried using CSS gradients, multiple background images, and blending modes, but wasn't able to achieve what I wanted. Also, wasn't able to find what I needed by googling.

Comment: Have you explored `key-frame` transitions?

Comment: I think there is an answer for you here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713813/fade-image-to-transparent-like-a-gradient ;)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not trying to do animation.

Comment: Oh I see, for some reason I read it as "fade in together" - my mistake

Comment: @The_Death_Raw That gets me closer, but [it doesn't support IE or Edge](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask).

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution using the mask-image property.

Scale the browser window to see the images cross fade.

```css
#Wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

#Left,
#Right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#Left {
  left: 0;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqa1P.jpg') top left no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 1));
  background-size: contain;
}

#Right {
  right: 0;
  background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvGLY.jpg') top right no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div id="Wrap">
  <div id="Left"></div>
  <div id="Right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted since this does what I need. Unfortunately, [it isn't supported by IE or Edge](http://caniuse.com/#search=mask)... I'll accept your answer tomorrow if no one can find a way to do it with better browser compatibility.

Comment: @NathanArthur Thanks, is anything supported in IE. It's been holding us developers back for decades, time it went in the bin lol.

Answer (score 0):

i have made you an example with backgrounds. position relative + both gradients bgs. maybe this works with your pictures

```
<body>
 <div style="position:relative">
  <div id="grad1">Image1asBG</div>
  <div id="grad2">Image2asBG</div>
 </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
    #grad1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width:100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0), rgba(255,0,0,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}

#grad2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width:100%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,0,1), rgba(255,255,0,0)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,0,1), rgba(255,255,0,0)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255,255,0,1), rgba(255,255,0,0)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,2550,0,1), rgba(255,255,0,0)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/d8v23w60/1/

Comment: These are nice, but don't explain how this would be done using images.

Answer (score 0):

I used `opacity`. Here is a working copy. I hope it will help you.

Try like this:

```css
#img1 {
position:relative;
}
#img2 {
position:absolute;
left:5px;
opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvGLY.jpg" width="400" id="img1">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqa1P.jpg" width="200" id="img2">
```

Comment: It might work in some situations, but I need them to gradually blend into each other, where one image is at full opacity on one side, and the other is at full opacity at the other side, and the two images decrease in opacity towards the center, in effect.

Comment: So do you want the animation effect as well as ?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I guess my question wasn't clear enough. I don't need animation. I need [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/39766/2633).

Comment: Ok . let me try .

Comment: Can you check this https://codepen.io/alexcarpenter/pen/LveDx.. see if it is helpful

Comment: That's nice, too, but it's blending one image into a color instead of one image into another image.